# Allocation error that only appears sometimes

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

I have two classes World and WorldManager:

WorldManager.h

```
const sf::Vector2u roomSize = sf::Vector2u(30, 25);
const sf::Vector2u tileSize = sf::Vector2u(32, 32);

const unsigned int nb_tiles = 30*25;

const sf::Vector2u tilesetSize = sf::Vector2u(4, 9);
const sf::Vector2u textureSize = sf::Vector2u(360, 360);

class WorldManager
{
    public:
        WorldManager();

        void createWorld(sf::Texture tileset);
        std::vector<sf::Vertex> generateMap(std::array<unsigned int,nb_tiles> pattern);

    private:
        World m_world;
};
```

*(by the way, why can I not write `const unsigned int nb_tiles = roomSize.x*roomSize.y;`? I tells me I can't use it in a constant expression for the std::array)*

WorldManager.cpp

```
    #include "WorldManager.h"

WorldManager::WorldManager() :
    m_world()
{
    sf::Texture tileset;
    assert(tileset.loadFromFile("./sprites/tileset.png"));

    std::cout << "step 0";
    createWorld(tileset);
    std::cout << "step 4";
}

void WorldManager::createWorld(sf::Texture tileset)
{
    std::array<unsigned int,nb_tiles> pattern =
        {
            20, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 21,
            19, 12,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, 13, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 17,
            19, 14, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 17,
            22, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 23
        };

    std::cout << sizeof(pattern);

    std::vector<sf::Vertex> room = generateMap(pattern);

    std::cout << "step 1";
    m_world.loadTileset(tileset);
    std::cout << "step 2";
    m_world.loadRoom(room);
    std::cout << "step 3";
}

std::vector<sf::Vertex> WorldManager::generateMap(std::array<unsigned int,nb_tiles> pattern)
{
    std::vector<sf::Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.reserve(roomSize.x * roomSize.y * 4);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < roomSize.x; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < roomSize.y; ++j)
        {
            unsigned int cell = i * roomSize.x + j;

            vertices[cell*4].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+1].position = sf::Vector2f((i+1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+2].position = sf::Vector2f((i+1) * tileSize.x, (j+1) * tileSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j+1) * tileSize.y);

            unsigned int texCol = pattern[cell] % tilesetSize.x;
            unsigned int texLine = floor(pattern[cell] / tilesetSize.x);

            vertices[cell*4].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texCol * textureSize.x, texLine * textureSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((texCol+1) * textureSize.x, texLine * textureSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((texCol+1) * textureSize.x, (texLine+1) * textureSize.y);
            vertices[cell*4+3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(texCol * textureSize.x, (texLine+1) * textureSize.y);
        }

    return vertices;
}
```

World.h

```
class World
{
public:
    World();

    void loadTileset(sf::Texture tileset);
    void loadRoom(std::vector<sf::Vertex> room);

private:
    sf::Texture m_tileset;
    std::vector<sf::Vertex> m_room;

};
```

World.cpp

```
#include "World.h"

World::World()
{

}

void World::loadTileset(sf::Texture tileset)
{
    m_tileset = tileset;
}

void World::loadRoom(std::vector<sf::Vertex> room)
{
    m_room = room;
}
```

The sizeof returns 3000 bytes.

Then when I compile & run the program a few times, I randomly get:

- either the program ends and my console displays `step0 step1 step2 step3 step4 std::bad_alloc`
- or the program crashes and it displays `step0 step1 step2 step3` which is weird because step4 is just after step3.

I think the problem comes from the std::array, maybe it doesn't but it's the only thing I'm not familiar with. That array isn't that big though, is it?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
  // __p is not permitted to be a null pointer.
  void
  deallocate(pointer __p, size_type)
  { ::operator delete(__p); }
```

Comment: Use debugger and step through each line to see where it crashes.

Comment: BTW: `std::array` requires size to be known at compile time. `sf::Vector2u` is constructed at runtime, therefore it can't be used to initialize compile-time constant( then `std::array` won't accept it, since it's no longer compile time constant).

Comment: What is the definition of `sf::Vector2u`?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and take particular note of the link to debugging small programs at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @PcAF : the error occurs after the cout of "step 3", that is to say at the end of the function. It redirects me to `new_allocator.h`, to this function: [EDIT] : I edited my first post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : It's a template class with two coordinates.

Comment: After other tests, it seems to come from the reserve. Is it also impossible to do a reserve with these `sf::Vector2u`?